# HTML only open one tab contain download response

Tags: javascript, ajax, download

I'm trying to create a button which trigger to download some files when pressed.
This is my `js` code:

```js
$menu.find('li').click(function () {
    var selectedData = that.getAllSelections();
    let data = {
        'order_numbers': []
    };
    selectedData.forEach(element => {
        data['order_numbers'].push(element['ordernumber']);
    });
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: window.location.pathname + '/check/pdf',
        data: data,
        method: 'post',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result['status'] == 200) {
                result['data'].forEach(orderNumber => {
                    let downloadUrl = window.location.pathname + '/download/pdf/' + orderNumber;
                    window.open(downloadUrl, '_blank');
                });
                displayError(result['message'], 'success');
            } else {
                displayError(result['message']);
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            displayError('Something went wrong. Please try again');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is how it works. When button clicked, it can get list of filename to be downloaded. Then I'll call an `api` by `ajax` to check if these files is exist. This `api` will return an array of filename existed. Next step I use a for loop to open a bulk of tab, each tab call to an `api` which will download corresponding file.

My problem is, when I clicked download button, only one tab opened, therefore just 1 file downloaded. I've checked network in browser, `api` called by `ajax` return succes response. I also checked download file by file and all files can be downloaded.

Anyone can point where problem come from?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of opening a new tab, maybe you can generate mulitple hidden `<a>` with the [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#download) and trigger the click event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have found where problem come from. It's browser problem, it automatic blocks when too many tab open. Just change setting and it works.

Answer (score 1):

instead of calling `window.open(downloadUrl, '_blank')` pass a constant name as second argument.
This way, [its content will be replaced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Examples).

> If a window with the name already exists, then url is loaded into the existing window.